# How can I manually join cached Entity Framework objects?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, caching

I'm having a performance issue with lookups using the navigation properties of an EF model.

My model is something like this (conceptually):

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public EntityCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public EntityReference<Company> CompanyReference { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I want to get a list of all **Companies** that have (known) **Employees**.

Additionally, assume that I've already cached lists of the both the **Companies** and the **Employees** through previous calls:

```
var dbContext = new EmploymentContext();

var allCompanies = dbContext.Companies.ToList();
var allEmployees = dbContext.Employees.ToList();

bool activeCompanies = 
        allCompanies.Where(company => company.Employees.Any()).ToList();
```

This (in my environment) generates a new SQL statement for each **.Any()** call, following the *Employees* navigation property.

I already have all the records I need in my cached lists, but they're not 'connected' to each other on the client side.

I realize I can add .Include() calls to my initial cache-fill statement. I want to avoid doing this because in my actual environment I have a large number of relations and a large number of lists I'm populating up front. I'm caching largely to keep Linq from generating overly-complicated nested SQL statements that tend to bog down my database server.

I also realize I can modify my query so as to do an in-memory join:

```
bool activeCompanies = allCompanies.Where
(
    company => allEmployees.Any(employee => employee.CompanyID == company.ID)
);
```

I'm trying to avoid doing such a rewrite, because the actual business logic gets rather involved. Using Linq statements has significantly improved the readability of this logic, and I'd prefer not to lose that if at all possible.

---

So my question is this: can I connect them together manually somehow, in the way that the Entity Framework would connect them?

I'd like to continue to use the **.Any()** operator, but I want it to examine only the objects I have in memory in my **dbContext** - without going back to the database repeatedly.

Comment: You must decide whether your query is performed on the database (LINQ to Entities) or the (LINQ to objects) cache. 
If the query is made on the cache, **the cache must be complete**: the Employees property must be filled through the use of the `Include` function. Otherwise, the lazy loading mechanism will actually perform a query in the database for each subquery `company => company.Employees.Any()`.

Comment: @nlips - I guess that's my question: is there a way to complete the cache outside of the `Include` function, or after-the-fact?